# Awk output pipe as an argument in a loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, bioinformatics

I have some files to parse and use the output in an argument of a second program I'm using:

```sh
for file in ./*.vcf.gz; do
        echo "gunzip -c ${file} | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=\"\t\"} NR == FNR{key[\$1]=\$2; next} \$1 in key{\$1=key[\$1]} 1' ./map | cut -f1-6 | sed '1,6d' | vep -i -o ./"${file}"_dnds --compress_output gzip --dir_cache ./" 
done
```

But it is falling at the awk command where

```sh
gunzip -c ${file} | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=\"\t\"} NR == FNR{key[\$1]=\$2; next} \$1 in key{\$1=key[\$1]} 1' ./map input
```

then for the last pipe passage into the vep program, I also don't know how to make it so that the output goes into -i input, as in:

```sh
vep -i input -o ./"${file}"_dnds --compress_output gzip --dir_cache ./"
```

These are huge text files. How can I do this without reading into temporary files?

Comment: Just checking: Are you aware of the https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ site?

Comment: No wasn't! thxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Variant Effect Predictor from EnsEMBL reads from standard input by default ([documentation here](https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/vep_options.html)).

This means that leaving off the `-i` option completely (along with its option-argument) will make it read its input from the pipe.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do in your pipeline, but it looks as if you are trying to replace some identifiers with others, read from a separate file.  While doing so you use an `awk` program that has useless backslashes in it.  The `awk` command can be written as

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } NR == FNR { key[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in key) { $1=key[$1] } 1' map -
```

The `-` input filename makes `awk` read from its standard input when it gets to it (after processing the file called `map`).

`awk` is a more powerful language than what your pipeline gives it credit for, and you can easily incorporate both the `cut` and `sed` code into it:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } NR == FNR { key[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in key) { $1=key[$1] } FNR > 6 { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 }' map -
```

Your script may look something like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./*.vcf.gz; do
    gzip -cd "$file" |
    awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } NR == FNR { key[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in key) { $1=key[$1] } FNR > 6 { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 }' map - |
    vep -o "${file}_dnds" --compress_output gzip --dir_cache ./ 
done
```

(note also the correct double-quoting of the variable expansions)

Would you want to remove the `.vcf.gz` filename suffix from the name of the output file before appending `_dnds` to the end of it, use `vep -o "${file%.vcf.gz}_dnds" ...`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the first part of the question is solved by making awk treat stdin as a regular file

```
gunzip -c ${file} | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=\"\t\"} NR == FNR{key[\$1]=\$2; next} \$1 in key{\$1=key[\$1]} 1' ./map -
```

but still can't figure how to pipe the parsed output into

```
vep -i input -o ./"${file}"_dnds --compress_output gzip --dir_cache ./
```